# Не обновляется страница после изменения ее исходного кода

Tags: apache, кэширование, php, apache2

Есть VDS со стандартными настройками Apache + PHP... На нем размещен сайт (виртуальный хост).
Мои действия:

1. Открываю в браузере страницу сайта, вижу версию А страницы.
2. Изменяю PHP-скрипт, который эту страницу отдает. Ожидаю, что после перезагрузки страницы в браузере увижу версию B страницы.
3. Перезагружаю страницу в браузере, вижу версию A. Чищу кэш, жму N-е количество раз на F5 - страница не меняется.
4. Через какое-то время (минуты через 2-10, не засекал) опять обновляю страницу, и наконец вижу версию B страницы.

В логах посещений Apache записываются при этом все запросы к CSS, JS и изображениям, сама же страница (.php) по логам вообще не загружалась. Менял браузеры - ничего не меняется.

Настройку Apache и PHP делал хостер, с ней работает панель управления (в ней перетыкал все настройки, не помогает ничего). Стоит Nginx, с ним не работал.

Подскажите, будьте любезны, как отключить (этот кэш) это?

Comment: @therainycat, лучше всего спросить самого хостера. Вообще это может быть apc (потому что кэшировать вообще всю динамику это как-то очень жестко со стороны хостера), но тогда непонятно, почему он не реагирует на обновления файлов.

Comment: Можно попробовать отправить из PHP заголовки на запрет кеширования, правда не знаю, насколько это поможет.

    header("Expires: Thu, 19 Feb 1998 13:24:18 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, у хостера по умолчанию стояло кэширование (настройка Nginx), достаточно странное. Т.к. это - панель управления Vesta, в ней все исправилось редактированием виртуального хоста с последующей установкой шаблона Nginx в default (стояла cached).

<sub>(Перенесено из вопроса)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

На reg.ru хостинге в php.ini нужно добавить:
opcache.enable=Off

Comment: Какое отношение к вопроу имеет reg.ru хост?

Answer (score -1):

В `php.ini` нужно добавить:

```
opcache.enable=Off
```

Pаботает.